# Returning a number rather than the entries

Tags: sql, oracle10g

This sql returns the actors that have more than role in the database but how do I amend this so that it will just return the number of actors who have more than three roles? for example just return the number 3.

```
SELECT ACTORID
FROM ROLE
GROUP BY actorID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
SELECT count(1) from (SELECT ACTORID
FROM ROLE GROUP BY actorID HAVING COUNT(*) > 3)
```

Comment: Mind you, the other answers are probably a bit more efficient. For small tbales, it doesn't really matter

Comment: The other queries are functionally different.  This returns the count of actors, the others return the count of roles for each actor.